# Конвертация docx в pdf через Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, pdf, docx, apache-poi

Задача такая, нужно создать печатную форму, поля заменить на нужные данные и сконвертировать в pdf формат.
Замена текста и сохранение в формате docx происходит корректно.
Но когда я запускаю:

PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, outputStream, pdfOptions);

То поля которые были заменены, они отсутствуют в pdf файле..
Поля в форме заносятся в форму для текса (фигуру), на фото видно.
Если вставлять в обычный текст то замена проходит корректно.

Думаю, что нужно как то настроить PdfOptions, но пока нет вариантов как это сделать..
Если у кого то была такая проблема и есть предложения что можно попробовать сделать, буду рад за помощь))

Код который конвертируют готовую форму:

```
    InputStream inputStream = ByteSource.wrap(printFileDTO.getContent()).openStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    PdfOptions pdfOptions = PdfOptions.create();
    
    pdfOptions.fontProvider((familyName, encoding, size, style, color) -> {
        try {
            BaseFont baseFont =
                    BaseFont.createFont(TNR, encoding, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            return new Font(baseFont, size, style, color);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });

    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, outputStream, pdfOptions);
```

Кусок заполненной формы:

[image: Кусок заполненной формы]

Comment: не думаю, что это конвертация docx в pdf возможна средствами poi. то есть вы, разумеется, сможете что-то сконвертировать, но всегда останутся какие-то кривые или необработанные элементы, типа футеры, хедеры итд. вся проблема в том, что эти форматы находятся в монополии у известных компаний и с ними делают что хотят. а когда от версии к версии меняется что угодно, то довольно сложно вносить изменения в сторонние библиотеки тира poi. единственный способ, который мне иизвестен для такого вида конвертации (с корректным результатом) - document4j.

Comment: минус в том, что она использует нативные виндовые и офисные либы для конвертации, так что запустить ее под линуксом не получится. т.е. еси такое запускать на серваке, то только на виндовом. либо юзать сторонние апихи (которые тоже юзают documents4j на виндовом серваке). вот такое веселье

Comment: Спасибо за коментарий)

Comment: В этом то и проблема) Пишется на винде а работает на линуксе. И для винды document4j работает хорошо и без проблем, но на линуксе он не может работать. Вот и хотелось бы найти какое то решение, использоваться эту библиотеку на линуксе)

Comment: могу только пожелать удачи))